# Parsing CSV NSString to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsstring, nsarray

I want to change the format of the CSV read in my code.  The original format is:

> Latitude, Longitude, Name, Country, Number

For example:

> -80.26262, 25.81015, Everglades Motel, USA-United States, +1 305-888-8797

I want to use a file of the following format:

> time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type

For example:

> 2015-05-18T04:06:21.250Z,34.0221667,-116.4003333,9.05,0.83,ml,12,151,0.04781,0.11,ci,ci37164151,2015-05-18T04:10:34.999Z,"11km SSE of Yucca Valley, California",earthquake

I should preface this by saying I know very little about NSString conventions.  Now, the original code gets the CSV file to parse like this:

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"quakes" ofType:@"csv"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSInteger count = lines.count - 1;

    TBQuadTreeNodeData *dataArray = malloc(sizeof(TBQuadTreeNodeData) * count);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        dataArray[i] = TBDataFromLine(lines[i]);
    }

    TBBoundingBox world = TBBoundingBoxMake(19, -166, 72, -53);
    _root = TBQuadTreeBuildWithData(dataArray, count, world, 4);
```

The code then parses the resulting NSString like this:

```
TBQuadTreeNodeData TBDataFromLine(NSString *line)
{
NSArray *components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
double latitude = [components[1] doubleValue];
double longitude = [components[0] doubleValue];

TBHotelInfo* hotelInfo = malloc(sizeof(TBHotelInfo));

NSString *hotelName = [components[2] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
hotelInfo->hotelName = malloc(sizeof(char) * hotelName.length + 1);
strncpy(hotelInfo->hotelName, [hotelName UTF8String], hotelName.length + 1);

NSString *hotelPhoneNumber = [[components lastObject] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
hotelInfo->hotelPhoneNumber = malloc(sizeof(char) * hotelPhoneNumber.length + 1);
strncpy(hotelInfo->hotelPhoneNumber, [hotelPhoneNumber UTF8String], hotelPhoneNumber.length + 1);

return TBQuadTreeNodeDataMake(latitude, longitude, hotelInfo);
}
```

I changed the code so the component numbers were right for my string (lat = 1, long = 2, name = 13, number = 4) and I tried changing the code to not trim for whitespace (I just made it " NSString *hotelName = components[2]; ") but neither thing worked (alone or in unison).  I also tried getting rid of the +1s.  My data is being read- it NSLogs fine, it just doesn't parse to the map.  Perhaps this is because of commas in quotation marks in my code.  If so, or otherwise, how can I fix this?

Comment: Parsing CSV is a lot harder than most people think. Note in your updated CSV file you have values in quotes that contain commas in the value. You can't do simple string splitting for real world CSV files. Use a well written CSV parsing library such as https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! @rmaddy thanks, will do.

Comment: BTW - since your question is simply about parsing CSV data, update your question by removing all of the needless references to the map view and the clustering library.

Comment: @rmaddy OK done, thanks.  I will work w/ your recommended library to solve the issue, and if I beat the internet at large to the solution will update with the relevant key to this riddle :)

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think the comma in the quotation marks is an issue.  It is allowed by the Basic Rules of CSV (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples)

Comment: Yes, the comma is allowed due to the quoted. My point is that your simplistic string parsing can't deal with the comma in the quotes. That is why I suggested a proper CSV parsing library.

Comment: I have a CSV parser published on GitHub ([click here](https://github.com/RedHandTech/RHCSVParser)). You can either use it as is or take a look and use it to help build your own.

Comment: Thanks @RASS and I understand your point now rmaddy (can't at you because only one allowed sorry) and will work on using a more complex parser from one of your suggestions.